# Slider для перемотки аудиофайла xcode

Tags: slider, xcode

При изменении положения ползунка слайдера- хочу как обычно в проигрывателе чтоб  перематывалась песня
Не хочет работать, по нажатию играет заново трек

```
- (IBAction)sliderButton:(UISlider *)sender
```

{
           _player.currentTime =sender.value;
     [self updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:_player];

}
-(void)updateCurrentTimeForPlayer:(AVAudioPlayer *)p
{
       _slider.value = p.currentTime;
}

как правильно сделать

Comment: решил вопрос

Answer (score 1):

У меня отлично работает вот это:

```
- (IBAction)songProgressBarValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {
    [self.user.context.musicPlayer.player seekToTime:CMTimeMake(sender.value, 1)];
}
```

при условии, что плээер - объект класса `AVPlayer *player`;

Comment: спасибо за ответ - нашел видео в нете уже